# Reading file content using windows batch file and executing a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

It looks like duplicate question but it is not.

I have two files

- Users.txt - contains 5 user names
- Prg.bat - this program should read each line and execute an ldapsearch command.

I tried below commands but nothing worked.

```
For /F "eol=*"%%G in ("c:\temp\users.txt") do @echo %%G
```

Am i missing something here.

My output should show user1, user2,user3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You quote the path so the iteration is assumed to be over the literal string not the file, simply remove them:

```
For /F "eol=* "%%G in (c:\temp\users.txt) do @echo %%G
```